# How to export selected columns of list in react admin?

Tags: react-admin

I have a list view in react admin.

I want to export the data that this list view contains with the export button.

However, I don't want to include one of the columns in the exported file.

Is there a way to customise the columns that you want to export in react admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a custom component to the `exporter` prop on your List

(React-Admin docs) https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#exporter